# Best way to reference Bootstrap in a Grails 3 app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, grails-3.0

I'm wanting to pull in Twitter's Bootstrap into my Grails 3 app.  What's the best way to do this?  I neither want to place the source under version control nor reference remote CDNs.

Adding `"org.grails:grails-bootstrap:3.0.1"` as a compilation dependency in my `build.gradle` pulls down the associated JAR, but how do I plumb this into my application to ultimately be able to reference Bootstrap classes from my views/GSPs?

Comment: Can you show how you add webjar to you project?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  could you document the result?  Interestingly, there is a reference to bootstrap in application.css already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Webjars worked for me, I've used the webjars link in my `application.js` and in my `application.css`, but the links are not always well defined (see typeahead example)

application.js:

```
//= require jquery-2.1.3.js
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= require /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min
//= require /webjars/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.5/bootstrap-tagsinput
//= require /webjars/typeaheadjs/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.js
```

application.css:

```
/*
*= require main
*= require mobile
*= require_self
*= require /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme
*= require /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap
*= require /webjars/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.5/bootstrap-tagsinput
*/
```

Comment: How you reference to webjars? as dependecy? I receive error during compile, that no such assets '/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme' and for all other links. In cache of grails I see webjar, but seems like it should be placed in 'assets' folder of grails project?

Comment: you need to add the dependency in your build.gradle file (see [webjars](http://www.webjars.org/) to look up the dependency of your needs). For bootstrap 3.3.5 it is: `compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.5'`.

Comment: Yes, I have do it before write a comment. So error appears with dependency. Some other actions performed?

Comment: nope  `dependencies {
...
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile 'org.webjars:typeaheadjs:0.11.1'
    compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.5'
    compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap-tagsinput:0.5'
    compile 'org.webjars.bower:bootstrap-table:1.8.1'
...
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
...
    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}`

Comment: I have add only this compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.5', may be I should add some other webjar to proper work. I'll check, thanks.

Comment: Are you able to add attributes like `media="screen, projection"` to the full css include? e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.css?compile=false" media="screen, projection">`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any usable Bootstrap plugin for Grails 3 yet. I think it is easier to include [WebJars](http://www.webjars.org) Bootstrap in your project and then reference the files in your gsp's or layouts.

I don't have a workable example ready, but take a look at this code snippet: 
https://github.com/canoo/open-dolphin-lazybones-templates/commit/d1a2c3bc4d0852a331f66287314b6348d6e76e14

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [this plugin](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin) and the documentation tells you exactly what to do.

Javascript grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Stylesheet grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.css:

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*/
```

Comment: Hi Gregg.  The documentation references BuildConfig.groovy, which I believe has been discontinued in Grails 3.  Could you advise how to reference this plugin in the "new" way?

Comment: Wouldn't you add it to your build.gradle? I'm sorry, I honestly don't know for sure. I'm avoiding Grails 3. :) Assuming it is still using the asset-pipeline I'd still believe it applies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this plugin [kensiprell/bootstrap-framework](https://github.com/kensiprell/bootstrap-framework) and added following path into `.gitignore` so that resources are downloaded upon first run.

```
/grails-app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap
/grails-app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap-all.js
/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome
/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap
/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome-less.less
/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-less.less
/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-all.css
/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome-all.css
```